# Empty or not parsable input -> field border gets red

Tags: java, javafx

I have this code for checking if the input is `Long` variable:

```
public void validateTextFieldLong (TextField textField, PseudoClass errorClass){
        textField.focusedProperty().addListener((arg0, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            try {Long.parseLong(textField.getText().trim()); 
                 textField.pseudoClassStateChanged(errorClass, false);
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e){
                System.out.println(e);
                textField.pseudoClassStateChanged(errorClass, true);
            }
    });}
```

and this one for checking empty field when focus is lost

```
public <T extends Node> void validateNodeForEmptyByPredicate(
    T node,
    PseudoClass errorClass,
    Predicate<T> predicate
) {
    node.focusedProperty().addListener((arg0, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (!newValue) {
            node.pseudoClassStateChanged(errorClass, predicate.test(node));
        }
    });
}
```

They don't work together, when the variable is not Long, the border is red when focused, but when the focus is lost border is not red even though the input is not parsable.

How to check for empty field and not parsable value in the same method, and achieve border to be red when the field is empty or not parsable?

Comment: You should add the logic of method `validateTextFieldLong` in method `validateNodeForEmptyByPredicate`. Better, create an utility class with the logic and use it in both methods.

Comment: Can you show that in your answer please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it. If someone has a better solution please show us.

```
private boolean isParsable = false;
public void validateTextFieldLong2 (TextField textField, PseudoClass errorClass){
        textField.focusedProperty().addListener((arg0, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            try {Long.parseLong(textField.getText().trim());
                isParsable = true;
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e){
                System.out.println(e);
                isParsable = false;
            }

            if (!newValue) { //when focus lost
                if(textField.getText().trim().isEmpty() || !isParsable){
                    textField.pseudoClassStateChanged(errorClass, true);
                }
                else textField.pseudoClassStateChanged(errorClass, false);
            }
        });
    }
```